# Twilio delivers long SMS messages in random order

Tags: twilio

When my Twilio numbers receive an SMS longer than 160 chars, I get a call to my server with each 160 char fragment. Each server call is like a separate SMS. The order in which I receive them is random.

Does anyone have a solution to this other than manually assemble these fragments?

Does anyone know of a replacement to Twilio?. It should support:

- sending and receiving SMS world wide.
- sending and receiving SMSs that are longer than 160 chars. (i.e. deliver multiple messages in the right order)
- easy python/django integration.

Checked out Plivo's API. Did not find a solution there for receiving long SMSs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) does what I need.
It works all over the globe.
It solves the problem of [long inbound SMSs](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/handle-inbound-message)